# Drupal Views: Taxonomy Stripes for Calendar

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, datetime

I've got a bit of an issue with taxonomy stripes on Calendar.
If I wanted to define colour stripes for Content Types, I get this choice:

[image]

Simple. I just choose the type and add a colour.
However, I want to do it for Taxonomy. So I choose Taxonomy in the Stripes menu:

[image]

I successfully link it to the relevant taxonomy field, but I see no option for colour choice?

I'm using the most recent stable version of the calendar and the views modules.

How do I do this?
Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest development snapshot. See http://drupal.org/node/1392306#comment-5581466 for the patch.